# Texture Painting Ground

Tags: texture-painting

[image]

I'm trying to texture paint the ground but I don't know how. I haven't been able to find a tutorial that can help. All the terrain is one mesh and I'm using 2.82. I want to add some gravel around were the tracks are and do some grass variations.

Also I had to scale up the UV map to tile the texture here so that the grass texture didn't look so large.

Comment: Possible answer here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49705/texture-splatting-mix-multiple-4-textures