# Paint Pre-Made PBR Materials

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

What is the best way to paint an existing PBR Material (i.e. one that I have downloaded) onto a model? My first guess would have been using texture painting mode, but as far as I know, this only allows painting a single texture at the same time. This does not work with PBR Materials, b/c all of the different maps need to be painted at the same time in exactly the same way.

Is my assumption wrong on how to paint PBR Materials or is there another way that I can not see?

Comment: You can use a texture as a black and white mask for a mix shader switching between your pbr shader and another one

Comment: Yes, in my current model I could also use multiple materials and assign them to different surfaces. But I still have very noticeable seams because of UV unwrapping (the model mostly a cylinder) and I would like to paint the texture in such a way that it is seamless.

Comment: If using two or more materials inside a single shader tree, I'd suggest using the landscape masking set up with the 4 color split to be able to stencil multiple materials with some success.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49705/texture-splatting-mix-multiple-4-textures